# Send Email verification code with out asp.net core identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, email-validation

I know there is possible way to create&send email verification code using asp.net core identity. But in my case I dont want to setup all tables which asp.net core identity uses. I am thinking to create as a service to generate code by accepting email as input and provide api to verify.

Is there any nuget package or custom way to create email verification code with out asp.net core identity?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by yourself by creating one table to store the verification code and creat them using a random number generator. then you can have some controller action get this random code and check in the table that it matches the email.

Answer (score -1):

The basic idea behind most verification codes is by combining;

- a hidden secret
- some form of purpose for the token
- a per-user value like the email address
- a counter based on the current time.

eg `hash($"secret:email:{emailAddress}:{timestep}")`.

To verify, you would re-create the tokens for a small range of time values to see if any of them match.

The implementation used by asp netcore identity can be found on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Rfc6238AuthenticationService.cs).